# Increase width of <td>

Tags: html, css

How can I increase the width of a single `<td>` to 100% of the table?

I've tried `width="100%"` but It's not working.

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

[[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div style="background-color:rgba(72,118,191,0.5);" class="lightblue step1"><h2 class="paddingh2">Step 1</h2><div class="form-item form-type-slider form-item-step-2">
  <label for="edit-step-2">How effective is your new business generation?</label>
</div>
<table class="bigtable">
    <tr>
  <td style="font-style: normal;">Currently</td>
   <td style="font-style: normal;">With a CRM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>You ranked your process</td>
        <td>Your process could be</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php print $step1  . '/10'; ?></td>
        <td>9/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Your new business sales are:</td>
        <td>New business sales could increase by:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php print '£' . number_format($sales); ?></td>
        <td><?php print '£' . number_format($response1); ?></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>How will a CRM help us generate more business?</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Workbooks CRM improves new business by providing a single view of customers & prospects enabling you to drive specific marketing based on segmenting your lead data.

Reporting will enable management to ensure sales people are effective and following up leads and enquirers, whilst showing areas of potential focus (for example certain industries or marketing sources which bring in most leads).
</td>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

Comment: On the `<td>`, that you want to expand to 2 columns you need to change it to `<td colspan="2">` - http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/colspan-html-attribute/

Comment: @rkm_Hodor that wouldn't make the bottom row's text span 100% of the table, but 80%, as the browser would still be looking for another, empty, <td> after that has width 20%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row needs the same number of columns. Your first row currently has two `<td>`, so two columns. The last two rows only have one `<td>`, so one column. You can set the cell to span multiple columns using the `colspan` attribute:

**new code:**

```
<div style="background-color:rgba(72,118,191,0.5);" class="lightblue step1"><h2 class="paddingh2">Step 1</h2><div class="form-item form-type-slider form-item-step-2">
  <label for="edit-step-2">How effective is your new business generation?</label>
</div>
<table class="bigtable">
    <tr>
  <td style="font-style: normal;">Currently</td>
   <td style="font-style: normal;">With a CRM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>You ranked your process</td>
        <td>Your process could be</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php print $step1  . '/10'; ?></td>
        <td>9/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Your new business sales are:</td>
        <td>New business sales could increase by:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php print '£' . number_format($sales); ?></td>
        <td><?php print '£' . number_format($response1); ?></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">How will a CRM help us generate more business?</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Workbooks CRM improves new business by providing a single view of customers & prospects enabling you to drive specific marketing based on segmenting your lead data.

Reporting will enable management to ensure sales people are effective and following up leads and enquirers, whilst showing areas of potential focus (for example certain industries or marketing sources which bring in most leads).
</td>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked in the same div however when I create another table based off this one it still shows only at about 50% width? See about halfway down at: http://192.185.162.253/~sam/sales-calculator/thank-you

Comment: To confirm both these <td> elements had a colspan of 2

Comment: They both show spanning 100% to me. Could you highlight what's wrong on that page?

Comment: Thanks I figured it out!